# ggplot xlab number sequence in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot package in R to plot a simple point graph with the "Lecture" number on the xlab and the "music week" on the ylab.

Here is the simple dataset I'm trying to plot:

[image: Dataset - Music2]

Here is the code I used:

```
ggplot(music2, aes(Lecture, Music)) + geom_point() + xlab("Lecture") +     ylab("Music Week")
```

Here is the plot I get:

[image: point plot of dataset-music2]

As showed above in the plot, the xlab of the plot doesn't go in the sequence of the numbers as in the dataset. Number 11 and 12 jump in between 1 and 2, instead of staying behind 10.

How can I change the sequence into its natural order?

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). That said, your `Lecture` column is highly probably stored as a character variable (check the difference in alignment with `Music` column). To check the class: `class(dataset$Lecture)`. With `dataset$Lecture <- as.numeric(dataset$Lecture)` you can convert it to a numeric variable. If it is stored as a factor variable, use `as.numeric(as.character(dataset$Lecture))`. After that your plotting code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! I will improve next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the variable on the x-axis to a factor or at least it should not be of type character since in this case R tries to guess what the natural order of the characters should be

```
library(ggplot2)

# Example data. Replace with yours
data <- data.frame(a = 1:12, b = sample(c(0, 1)) )

ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(a), y = b)) + 
geom_point() + 
labs(x = "Label x", y = "Label y")
```